# Disable StackView onTouch() and enable only RecyclerView oTouch() (inside StackView ) android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, touch-event, stackview

I have a `StackView` which has `custom items` that contains `RecyclerView`.

I dont't want the user to switch the `stackview` by himself , instead I wanted it to switch it programmaticaly when all the questions inside the `RecyclerView` is answered .

When I scroll `StackView` gets switched some time , and `RecyclerView` scrolls sometime .

my code

```
rvScore.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
                    int action = e.getAction();
                    switch (action) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            rv.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

                }
            });
```

If need full code I can post it

[image]